# How can I lock a entry in a sqlite database using PDO?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, locking

For example, if I have this algorithm:

1. Connect to the database
2. Try selecting some data from the database
3. If the data doesn't exist

   1. Get the data from somewhere
   2. Insert the data to the database
4. Close database connection
5. Do something with the data
6. And we are done

Then, if the php script starts and the database doesn't have the data, maybe while generating it (step 3.1), another user starts the script again. Then, I think somethink like this is better:

1. Connect to the database
2. Try selecting some data from the database (if the entry is locked, the script waits until it is unlocked)
3. If the data doesn't exist

   1. Lock the database entry
   2. Get the data from somewhere
   3. Insert the data to the database
   4. Unlock the database entry
4. Close database connection
5. Do something with the data
6. And we are done

How can I do that *lock*? (I'm new to SQL, maybe there is a more appropriate name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the reading and the possible writing in the same [transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), then the database will ensure that two users will not interfere with each other.

(Read up on the [ACID properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).)